# How to make a "field" optional that gets data from an API

Tags: swift

Im having some trouble making a field optional. When I get some data from an API....

[image: Struct of API]

Above you can see the structs I'm using to decode the API data, and here is now an example where I get an error (the dates):

[image: Example of a request]

I always get this kind of error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 4", intValue: 4), CodingKeys(stringValue: "dates_timing", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "dates", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

My theory is because the "date" are [ ] Swift reads this as error even though I put everything as optional...

Comment: could you use text instead of images? And make your question with less overhead as possible.

Comment: I could but I figured it would be easier to understand with images sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`dates` is an array of arrays not an array of dictionaries

```
let dates:[[Dates?]]
```